# css I dont understand what turns on a transition

Tags: html, css

I am following a video tutorial about how to make a web site with css.
We made the menu mobile that appears when user click on toggle.
The tutor, to make nicer when it appears, added a new style .animate. It works but I don't understand what turns on the transitition.

Thanks
Frank

```css
body {background:#eee;}
.animate{
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.header{background:#333;}
.header_logo{color:#fff; float:left;display:block; padding:10px;}
.header_menu{float:right; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.header_menu_item{display: inline-block;}
.header_menu_item a{color:#fff; display:block; padding:15px;}
.header_menu_item a:hover{background-color: #000000;}
.header_icon-bar{display:block; float:right; padding:20px; display:none;}

.header_icon-bar span{display:block;height:3px; width:30px; background:#fff; margin-bottom:5px;}


/*------------------------
tablet m
--------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 998px){

 
}
/*------------------------
Smartphone
--------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 767px){
.header_icon-bar{display:block;}
.header_menu_item{display:block;}
.header_menu{width:100%; height:0px; overflow:hidden;}
.is-open{height:300px; overflow:auto;}
  
 
 
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/6.0.0/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
</head>

<body>
<header class="header clearfix">
<a href="" class="header_logo">logo</a>
<a href="" class="header_icon-bar">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</a>
<ul class="header_menu animate">
<li class="header_menu_item"><a href="">item</a></li>
<li class="header_menu_item"><a href="">item</a></li>
<li class="header_menu_item"><a href="">item</a></li>
<li class="header_menu_item"><a href="">item</a></li>
</ul>


</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.header_icon-bar').click(function(e){
   $('.header_menu').toggleClass('is-open');
   e.preventDefault();
 });//end toggle
 
 
}); //edn ready
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `.animate` has a **webkit/transition** for all (all css propieties), so when click on `.header_icon-bar` it adds another class `.is-open`...
`.is-open` has a **height 300px**, then with the class **animate** (and his transition) make the div going to *height:0 to height:300px*. 
If you add **transition(all)** to a class, and you change any css prop from this class, it will be animated.
Ref: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/
Cheers,

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean.

Comment: Ok. I'm glad you understood

Comment: Sorry I didn't finish my post ....
The problem for me is that always I see the transition with mouse event, in this case the mouse event is click on icon bar that adds a class to an other element the header, so pratically I see the transition just when the style .is-opne is applyed.
So why just when the new class is applyed and not before?? That is not clear for me.
Thanks

Comment: Because the new class is-open has a height:300px. So, from height:0 to height:300 it gonna be animated